# Data retrieval and display in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am new to Symfony, I have a table `users` with two columns: `user_name` and `first_name`, I want to display all users whose names (user_name & first_name) contains `$search`:

```
<?php

namespace Login\LoginBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Users;
use Login\LoginBundle\Modals\Login;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

public function homeAction(Request $request) {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $search_for = $request->get('search');

        //what to write here --save my life guys

    }
    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:home.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Show us your form?
I already answered something like that, look at the best way to make a search form => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733174/symfony2-form-is-always-empty-after-submitting/23733783#23733783

Comment: <form class="form-signin" method ="POST" action="{{path('login_login_home')}}" data-validate="parsley">
    <label>Search: <input type="text" name="search" class="search-query"></label>
     </form>I just create a form in the html file :

Comment: First you need to check symfony-doctrine manual for simple db select, When you are comfortable then try to make query and post here, Then here all are able to help you.

Comment: This question is really too broad for a good StackOverflow question, because it is essentially "How do I use Doctrine?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like a full process of querying and fetching data, passing the results to the template. What you need to do is following below steps:

1) Get the repository of your entity (table) and call your custom search function which is created in the repository (of course you can merge this step and next one to have all in your controller `homeAction` function) I assume your entity name is `Users`

```
public function homeAction(Request $request) {
   $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
   $results = array();
   if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
      $search_for = $request->get('search');
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $results = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Users')->searchPhrase($search_for);

   }

   return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:home.html.twig', array(
      'results' => $results
   ));
}
```

2) Now you need to build a repository class for you entity and implement below function in it *[Entity Repository in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)* (or merge the code below to your controller)

```
public function searchPhrase($phrase) {
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('U');
   $result = $query->where(
       $query->expr()->like('U.username', $query->expr()->literal("%$phrase%"))
   )
   ->andWhere(
       $query->expr()->like('U.firstName', $query->expr()->literal("%$phrase%"))
   )
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();

   return $results;
}
```

**Keep in mind because you mention "AND" I used `andWhere` whereas you can use `orWhere`; because you said "CONTAIN" I used `like` expression with % and that's the way you can create expression in DQL** Here is a full list of [Doctrine2 expressions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

3) last step is to show the results in your twig template; I assume you want to show them in table rows

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Username</th><th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    {% if results|length > 0%}
       {% for item in results %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ item.getUsername }}</td><td>{{ item.getFirstName }}</td>
    </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">No matching results found!</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
</table>
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks, looks better than mine, I will try it.

Comment: I tried , error !! Undefined method 'searchPhrase'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Comment: @bouraxwebmaster This problem is because in your entity you did not refer to the custom repository; you need to add something like `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="path\LoginLoginBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")` to top of your entity class

Comment: in my "entity" folder i have Users.php, so you mean I add this function to this file or to the controller ? and where I should put this @ORM ... ?

Comment: @bouraxwebmaster I don't know if you take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes but what you need is create another file called *UsersRepository* same as structure in the link; then put the function inside `UsersRepository` class; then you need to modify your *Users.php* just to add `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...")` on the top of the file (by default it's just `@ORM\Entity`) then the issue will be solved

Comment: same problem, I created a UserRepository in the Entity folder and put :    <?php
namespace Login\LoginBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LoginBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */

class UsersRepository {
    
    public function searchPhrase($phrase) {

Comment: Oh hold on; did you define the `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...")` inside your repository class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54473/discussion-between-javad-and-bourax-webmaster).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, But I this worked for me:

```
      $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Users');
          $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where("u.userName LIKE '%".$search_for."%' or u.firstName LIKE '%".$search_for."%'")
            ->getQuery();
          $Myusers = $query->getResult();
          if ($Myusers) //test if there are results returned
          {
              foreach ($Myusers as $user)
                {
                     echo "E-mail : ".$user->getUserName()." -- Name : ". $user->getFirstName()."<br>";

                }
          }
          else
          {
              echo "No matching results found!!";
          }
          //end-display
```

Comment: Why are echoing the results in your controller while you have a twig template?

Comment: Good question :) my solution is old-fashion php developer solution. just because I am new at this :) twig templating language is new for me (little bit different from HTML and CSS). I am still learning. Thank you.

Comment: No problem; In fact it's combination of HTML and CSS but the variable values should follow the twig syntax; anyway goodluck